# How to execute two different php prepared statements inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach, prepared-statement

I would like to get the value of a column, add a string to it, then update the column with the new value, and repeat this for every element of an array. I would like to use prepared statements, so my dream-code (which wouldn't work, I know)  would be:

```
$getcolumn = $link->prepare("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1");
$getcolumn->bind_param("i", $a_value);

$updatecolumn = $link->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `column`=? WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1");
$updatecolumn->bind_param("si", $newcolumnvalue, $a_value);

foreach($array as $a => $a_value) {             
    $getcolumn->execute();
    $getcolumn->bind_result($columnvalue);
    $getcolumn->fetch();

    $newcolumnvalue = $columnvalue.$addedstring;    

    $updatecolumn->execute();
}

$getcolumn->close();
$updatecolumn->close();
```

However, for it to work, I should close $getcolumn before executing $updatecolumn. But if I close $getcolumn inside the foreach loop, it won't be repeated for all the elements of the array. So how do I write this in a way that works, using prepared statements? Thank you in advance.

Comment: well you need to execute the first, fetch from the first, then update the second, why do you need the first statement for? can't you just use `concat(the column name, ?<placeholder>)` from mysql built-in with just a single update

Comment: I'm not familiar with concat. Please help me understand how I would be able to add a string to the fetched column value, before updating the column with the modified value, using concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the comments above, I'd suggest another way and use `CONCAT` of MySQL built-in function instead of fetching all the rows from the first prepare:

```
$updatecolumn = $link->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `column` = CONCAT(`column`, ?) WHERE id = ?");
$updatecolumn->bind_param("si", $addedstring, $a_value);
$updatecolumn->execute();
```

It just eliminates the first step that fetches the rows, this just updates the columns pertinent to that ID and concatenating the current columns value to that added string that you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. This was the missing piece in the puzzle. :)

Comment: @AnnaCivolani sure glad this helped